# Required entries in DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, dkim, ns-record, dns-zone

Writing a brief best practices technical document for in house.

- `A Records` for hostname / IP mapping
  (blank).mydomain.com
  www.mydomain.com
  *.mydomain.com   -can also add subdomain, ftp, cpanel, etc depending on setup
- `MX Records` (if sending and/or receiving email at this domain)
- `NS & SOA records` for Nameservers
- `TXT & possibly CNAME` for SPF / DKIM authentication depending on setup
  and needs

Are there any missing DNS records that should be added to *most* record sets?  Any changes or additions?

Comment: Personally I find this question a bit subjective. Other than SOA and NS records, the rest are optional as far as I'm concerned. Do I need a record for FTP? Not if I don't have an FTP server and even then I could call it whatever I want. This is a bit like asking "What kind of cheese should I have on my sandwich?".

Comment: Thanks Joe.  That's why I'm asking.  Obviously a lot are subjective but are any important ones missing or misconfigured?  And how about Havarti?

Answer (score 1):

`PTR` for reverse dns lookups

`AAAA` for IPv6 hosts (you clearly aren't doing IPv6 today, but certainly any new best practices should mention this).

In some ideal world, `RRSIG`, `DNSKEY`, et al, for [DNSSEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions)

Comment: PTR would be necessary only if sending outbound mail from the domain or would I need it in other situations?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary under any circumstances, although you are correct that it's often used as a spam check.   However, if you are talking "best practices" you should definitely have PTR records for all your IPs.

Answer (score 1):

`SPF` should be included in your list.  You can use TXT for older systems but newer systems (client and server) support the SPF resource record.  [RFC4408](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408) suggest using both.